# Chromedriver unexpectedly quit

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

I'm using [nightwatch.js](http://nightwatchjs.org) version 0.9.8 with node v4.4.3 and I'm receiving the error "Chromedriver unexpectedly quit".

I've tried using different versions of nightwatch, selenium and chromedriver, but the same thing keeps happening.

Here's the output from selenium:

```
12:13:55.692 INFO - SessionCleaner initialized with insideBrowserTimeout 0 and clientGoneTimeout 1800000 polling every 180000
12:13:55.725 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{acceptSslCerts=true, phantomjs.binary.path=./lib/phantomjs, name=**my site** / Search, browserName=chrome, javascriptEnabled=true, chromeOptions={args=[start-kiosk], prefs={download={default_directory=./test-files/downloads/, prompt_for_download=false}}}, platform=ANY}]])
12:13:55.742 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{acceptSslCerts=true, phantomjs.binary.path=./lib/phantomjs, name=**my site**  / Search, browserName=chrome, javascriptEnabled=true, chromeOptions={args=[start-kiosk], prefs={download={default_directory=./test-files/downloads/, prompt_for_download=false}}}, platform=ANY}]
Starting ChromeDriver 2.13.307650 (feffe1dd547ee7b5c16d38784cd0cd679dfd7850) on port 25433
Only local connections are allowed.
12:13:56.196 INFO - Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
12:13:56.868 INFO - Detected dialect: OSS
12:13:56.883 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{acceptSslCerts=true, phantomjs.binary.path=./lib/phantomjs, name=**my site**  / Search, browserName=chrome, javascriptEnabled=true, chromeOptions={args=[start-kiosk], prefs={download={default_directory=./test-files/downloads/, prompt_for_download=false}}}, platform=ANY}]]
12:13:56.898 INFO - Executing: [get: https://**my site** ])
12:13:57.523 WARN - Exception thrown
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"73757.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.13.307650 (feffe1dd547ee7b5c16d38784cd0cd679dfd7850),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 19 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
System info: host: '**my computer** ', ip: '10.0.1.2', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_31'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, chrome={userDataDir=/var/folders/5w/jh9886055gndhfs4y3c8mfd40000gn/T/.org.chromium.Chromium.xwDlJP}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=54.0.2840.71, platform=MAC, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 23364f0f90fbb61bad760ccbeea45f6c
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:322)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$2.invoke(EventFiringWebDriver.java:103)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver.get(EventFiringWebDriver.java:162)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.ChangeUrl.call(ChangeUrl.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.ChangeUrl.call(ChangeUrl.java:25)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
12:13:57.526 WARN - Exception: unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"73757.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.13.307650 (feffe1dd547ee7b5c16d38784cd0cd679dfd7850),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 19 milliseconds
```

Additionally, chromedriver works fine in isolation:

```
Last login: Thu Oct 27 12:21:43 on ttys003
**path**/chromedriver ; exit;
➜  ~ **path**/chromedriver ; exit;
Starting ChromeDriver 2.25.426935 (820a95b0b81d33e42712f9198c215f703412e1a1) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Possibly, it's your driver causing the issue. Change the chrome driver version to 2.24.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed simply by `npm i -g chromedriver`.